# How could I rotate my watches display to a variable degree?

Tags: samsung-mobile, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app

I would like to rotate my watches display to a variable degree like a compass does in real life? So far I have only discovered this function within the samsung API

```
screen.lockOrientation("portrait-secondary");
```

I would like more control than this, if that means using the native API, that's fine but I need help on where to look.

Comment: Hi @Bob Saget, did my answer help you? No response from you till now.

Comment: Yes I think this will work, I was having trouble understanding the map concept but it looks like the function takes inputs that will allow me to rotate on the x axis to a variable degree. Thank you, I wouldn't have found this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using ***evas_map_util_rotate()*** function to rotate an object. It rotates the map based on an angle and the center coordinates of the rotation (the rotation point). A positive angle rotates the map clockwise, while a negative angle rotates the map counter-clockwise.

Please have a look into **Modifying a Map with Utility Functions** section of [***this link***](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/guides/native-application/user-interface/efl/transformation-evas-map?langredirect=1). It contains an example which shows how to rotate an object around its center point by 45 degrees clockwise.

You may also use below sample code snippet.

```
 @param[in] object_to_rotate The object you want to rotate
 @param[in] degree The degree you want to rotate
 @param[in] cx The rotation's center horizontal position
 @param[in] cy The rotation's center vertical position

void view_rotate_object(Evas_Object *object_to_rotate, double degree, Evas_Coord cx, Evas_Coord cy)
{
    Evas_Map *m = NULL;

    if (object_to_rotate == NULL) {
        dlog_print(DLOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, "object  is NULL");
        return;
    }

    m = evas_map_new(4);
    evas_map_util_points_populate_from_object(m, object_to_rotate);
    evas_map_util_rotate(m, degree, cx, cy);
    evas_object_map_set(object_to_rotate, m);
    evas_object_map_enable_set(object_to_rotate, EINA_TRUE);
    evas_map_free(m);
}
```

Hope it'll help.